# Sending emails using PHP, having troubles configuring the SMTP server

Tags: php, email, smtp

Trying to send an activation email for newly registered users, here's the code so far:

```
$to = $email;
$subject = "Activate your account!";
$headers = "From: noreply@test.com";    
$body = "..."

$mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

In the tutorial by phpacademy, the instructor used

```
ini_set("SMTP", $server);
```

I cannot figure out what to do. I think that my SMTP server should be my Yahoo account. How can I send the emails?

Comment: the SMTP setting is for windows servers only and contains the address to point your smtp server

Comment: Just use [PHPMailer](http://serverfault.com/questions/288107/how-to-put-my-web-site-online) or [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) and configure sending emails via SMTP directly (you will need to provide your Yahoo mailbox and password and it will be sent from Yahoo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to sending email with PHP mail function you have to setup a SMTP server first in your PC. Other way, you can use a class to do this with out setting any thing in your PC. [PHP mailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/PHPMailer%20v5.1/) known to do this with few lines:
here is an example from the site of the project:

```
<?php

require("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "smtp.example.com"; // SMTP server

$mail->From     = "from@example.com";
$mail->AddAddress("myfriend@example.net");

$mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
$mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
?>
```

Official web site: http://phpmailer.worxware.com

Answer (score 1):

No, your *account* is not the same as a *server*. Your `$server` variable should be set to a suitable hostname or IP address of an SMTP server, like `$server = "mail.myisp.net";`.

Check your email client to find out your own mail server, or ask your ISP.

Comment: Ok, so where can I find a server? Do I have to set one up on my computer?

Comment: If your computer is running a server already, then you can use that, yes -- so you could make `$server` just "127.0.0.1" or "localhost". If you're hosting your website somewhere, your webhost will definitely be able to tell you.

Comment: Localhost doesn't work, gonna try my IP adress. >>>Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set(

Comment: You're not running a mailserver locally then. Find another one!

Comment: Yahoo seems to have one, `smtp.mail.yahoo.com`, but I'm not sure if you can use it unencrypted and unauthenticated. If not, you'll have to set up your PHP a bit more to configure the credentials.

Answer (score 1):

`$server` should be the name (or IP address) of a machine that's running an SMTP server daemon and that you have access to. This should work with Yahoo's service (probably something like smtp.yahoo.com) but you'll need to provide a user and password if you're going to email an address that's not @yahoo.com. More common is to use a local server, like something your office/school would have configured for you. Or, if you're running a unix-ish OS, you can probably just skip the line completely and let it default to localhost.

Comment: I am not running Unix or anything like it, just Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

When I had to send activation emails to the users after the users registered I had considered the same SMTP route but even if you manage to get it going there are certain disadvantages using SMTP

1. Delay in sending out emails.
2. Emails considered spam
3. Config etc.

Try this out, it has been very cheap and reliable service for me so far. www.postmarkapp.com 
They have APIs that you can hook into using PHP. My sample PHP code that is in Production is as below.

```
    // Create a "server" in your "rack", then copy it's API key
define('POSTMARKAPP_API_KEY', 'xyz-blah-blah-blah');

// Create a "Sender signature", then use the "From Email" here.
// POSTMARKAPP_MAIL_FROM_NAME is optional, and can be overridden
// with Mail_Postmark::fromName()
define('POSTMARKAPP_MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'email address that you are sending from-google apps email in my case');
define('POSTMARKAPP_MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Description of the Sender name');

// Create a message and send it
Mail_Postmark::compose()
    ->addTo($to, $to)
    ->subject('whatever subject you want to put here for your email')
    ->messagePlain($pin_message)
    ->send();
```

Yes its that easy once you have created a virtual server with postmarkapp. Guess what first 1000 emails are free so you can try it out and if not use SMTP your way. After the first 1000 i think 5000 costs $7 or something. Really nice and cheap and I have had no downtime at all.

Try it out. You will like it. By the way I am not associated with postmark in any way its just that I like using their services. Check out my question when I was working on this before.

[PHP mail() function sends the email but it takes more than 10 mins to show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044502/php-mail-function-sends-the-email-but-it-takes-more-than-10-mins-to-show-up)

Answer (score 0):

if you're on a linux server you should check that the server as a smtp server installed, if not you'd better configure one in the php.ini  http://fr.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

Comment: Please give me further instructions on how to do this.

Comment: which OS are you using for your php server

Comment: so you just have to set the SMTP to a server you can send mail from as stated by @Alex or @Kerrek